# Form Not Validating Correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am working on a web form which is supposed to pass some validation rules once it's been submitted. The rule I'm having trouble with right now is that age is only supposed to be a number, for example (24 is ok, but 24 years-old should give an error).

Right now I'm trying to get it to accept only numeric content and have no spaces.

I also have a first name field that was not supposed to allow spaces and used the statement

```
if(!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(fName))) {
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Name cannot contain spaces";
    return false;
}
```

to check for whitespace and this worked properly (I'll be posting the full code at the end). So I thought I could do something similar with my checkAge() function, but I cannot get it to work. The form always submits regardless of if I've entered anything in the age field at all. However, if I leave the name field blank or enter an invalid input, I'm given the correct error.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 5</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            First Name: <input type="text" id="name"> <br>
            <span id="nameErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            Age: <input type="text" id="age"> <br>
            <span id="ageErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            Street Address: <input type="text" id="address"> <br>
            State: <select>
                <option value="la">LA</option>
                <option value="tx">TX</option>
                <option value="ok">OK</option>
                <option value="mi">MI</option>
                <option value="az">AZ</option>
            </select> <br>
            Login Password: <input type="password" id="password"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                return checkName() && checkAge();
            }

            function checkName() {
                var form = document.myForm;
                var fName = form.name.value;
                var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("nameErrMsg");
                if(fName.length < 3) {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Please enter a name with at least three letters";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(fName))) {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Name cannot contain spaces";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined; 
                }
            }

            function checkAge() {
                var form1 = document.myForm;
                var personAge = form1.age.value;
                var ageErr = document.getElementById("ageErrMsg");
                if(/\D/.test(personAge)) {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined;
                }
                else if(!(/\D/.test(personAge))) {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter a numeric age";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(personAge.length < 1) {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(personAge))) {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Age cannot contain spaces";
                    return false;
                }   
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also, as this is written I am getting no errors when I view the web console on my browser. Can anyone spot why this isn't working properly and/or have another way to accomplish the same task on the checkAge() function?

**Updated with Working Code**
Thanks for the help guys. I wanted to post the code now that it's working correctly because I ran into something that I've never come across before and hope that this could help anybody else that is having the same problem.

Even after implementing the accepted answer, I was getting the correct error messages, but only if I was only calling one function from my validateForm() function. I ended up assigning these function calls to variables and returning the variables from this function and that worked perfectly.

So here's the final working code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 5</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            First Name: <input type="text" id="name"> <br>
            <span id="nameErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            Age: <input type="text" id="age"> <br>
            <span id="ageErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            Street Address: <input type="text" id="address"> <br>
            State: <select>
                <option value="la">LA</option>
                <option value="tx">TX</option>
                <option value="ok">OK</option>
                <option value="mi">MI</option>
                <option value="az">AZ</option>
            </select> <br>
            Login Password: <input type="password" id="password"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                var ckName = checkName();
                var ckAge = checkAge();

                return ckName && ckAge;
            }

            function checkName() {
                var form = document.myForm;
                var fName = form.name.value;
                var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("nameErrMsg");
                if(fName.length < 3) {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Please enter a name with at least three letters";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(fName))) {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Name cannot contain spaces";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined; 
                }
            }

            function checkAge() {
                var form1 = document.myForm;
                var personAge = form1.age.value;
                var ageErr = document.getElementById("ageErrMsg");
                if(personAge === "") {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(/\D/.test(personAge)) {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter a numeric age";
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined;
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that the person age regex is passing when the field is left empty because an empty string doesn't contain any illegal characters. So you'll want to check for an empty string before you pass it through your regex checker.

The following code snippet should fix your issue:

```
if(personAge === "")
{
    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
    return false;
}
else if(/\D/.test(personAge))
{
    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter a numeric age";
    return false;
}
else
{
    ageErr.innerHTML = "";
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting the same result

Comment: Oh whoops, the first if should be checking against the personAge variable, not test. Updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of these checks with a single regular expression:

```
^\d+$
```

This ensures that the entry has one or more digits (\d is the character class [0-9], + is "one or more", ^ matches the beginning of the string and $ matches the end of the string.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! How would that work with displaying a different error message based on which rule failed though?

Comment: If you absolutely need to display different error messages, I would add more specific checks inside the else case of this test (e.g., /\w/ will match any white space). I think that the "Please enter a numeric age." would probably be enough, though. I'd also totally suggest finding and consuming a regular expression tutorial if you haven't already. They're really powerful, really useful, and really impenetrable if you don't know them.